# Alternatives to PHP for Wordpress plugins?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am creating (have been for a while) a website on Wordpress. Third party plugins by third parties have been very helpful, but most just are not perfect for what I am trying to create.

I am new to development/programming, and I am doing javascript right now and java in the future. I want to be able to create my own plugins, but is PHP the only language capable? I have read on multiple sites from multiple people that PHP is messy and unintuitive. I'd rather be able to use Python or Ruby.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WordPress is done in PHP, as such the plugins will need to be in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress is built on PHP, so yes you will have to stick with PHP to develop plugins for Wordpress.

And people with the thought that `PHP is messy and unintuitive` are probably still stuck in the old days of PHP. PHP as a language has received lots of attention and has been transformed completely from procedural to object oriented, and, as of PHP 5.4, it supports the most appealing OOP features including error handling exceptions, namespaces, traits, PDO (database abstraction layer) to name but a few.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll just stick to it.